# OpenCV for Android with NDK support: issue with updating from 4.1.0 to 4.1.1

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

I have written a tutorial for setting up OpenCV 4.1.0 for Android with NDK support. The tutorial is hosted on this [Github repository](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template). When trying to apply these instructions to Opencv 4.1.1 version, I get a black screen. What do I need to change to make it work for OpenCV 4.1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV 4.1.1 is permissions-aware. In **MainActivity.kt**, you need

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mOpenCvCameraView!!.setCameraPermissionGranted()
    }
}
```